# Draw error with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble with making my python app work.

I've made some classes for making my work easier, you can check them all [in this Github repo](https://github.com/CMakerA/WiSync).

My main class is:

```
from UI import *

window = Window(Size(1000, 700), "WiSync", "logo.png")

button1 = Button(Size(50, 30), Position(10, 10), UIThemes.light)
window.add(button1)

window.start()
```

It doesn't give me any error, but it just doesn't draw anything. I know that all the data is ok because in my drawer class I have a `print()` call:

```
def draw_rect(zone: Zone, color: Color, window: pygame.Surface):
    print("Drawing rect " + zone.to_string() + " with color " + color.to_string())
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color.get(), zone.get())
```

And in my app loop there's a continuous message: `Drawing rect Zone(10, 10, 60, 40) with color flat_light_sea_blue`, but it doesn't show anything in the screen.

Sorry if I haven't been clear enough, but I am Spanish and this is hard to explain. If you have any other doubts, please ask.

Thanks for your help, you are awesome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not calling `pygame.display.update()` anywhere in your code.

You are indeed drawing these `Rect`s but they will not be seen on your monitor unless this line is in your main event loop/main game loop.

**To fix this problem:**

- Simply add the line `pygame.display.update()` at the end of your main loop after all drawing has been done.

In your repo, I looked at [UI.py](https://github.com/CMakerA/WiSync/blob/master/UI.py). In the `__main_loop` method of the `Window` class, there is no line `pygame.display.update()` which is of course needed.

Here is the fixed code:

```
def __main_loop(self):
        while self.running:
            # Draw all the elements
            for element in self.elements:
                element.draw()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type is pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

             pygame.display.update()
```

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to leave a comment below!

Comment: Glad I could help!